# JQuery Limpar array ao fazer nova requisição

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Na `view` eu tenho um `input` select que no evento `onchange` eu executo uma chamada em `ajax` para uma determinada rota que busca todos os itens de um `Model`.

```
<select required onchange="getQuestions()" name="questionnaire_id" id="questionnaire_id" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                            @if(count($questionnaires) > 0)
                                @foreach($questionnaires as $item)
                                    @if($item->id == $anamnese->quest_id)
                                        <option selected value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>

function getQuestions(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {id: $('#questionnaire_id').val()},
        url: '/student-anamnese/questions/' + $('#questionnaire_id').val(),
        success: function(data){
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, item) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#col").append('<h3>Perguntas</h3>\
                <p class="text-success">' + item.name + '</p>\
                <input type="hidden" name="questionnaire_question_id[]" value="'+ item.id +'" />\
                <textarea required name="questionnaire_questions_answers[]" cols="80" placeholder="Digite a resposta aqui" rows="3" id="perguntas"></textarea>');
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Nessa chamada ajax, em success, eu renderizo alguns elementos html na tela. Eu preciso que quando o usuário mudar a opção no select, esses elementos html sejam apagados e renderize os novos elementos.

Comment: `$("#col").html('')` pode resolver, caso você queria excluir todos os dados do `#col`, mas se você tem mais coisa dentro e quer excluir apenas o que foi adicionado, você pode dar uma classe pra eles... que seria a forma mais simples e depois remove-los: `$('.nome_class').remove()`

Comment: O jQuery possui um método próprio para esvaziar elementos: `$("#col").empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função `beforeSend: function()` antes do `success` para realizar essa ação.

```
function getQuestions(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {id: $('#questionnaire_id').val()},
        url: '/student-anamnese/questions/' + $('#questionnaire_id').val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#col").html('');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, item) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#col").append('<h3>Perguntas</h3>\
                <p class="text-success">' + item.name + '</p>\
                <input type="hidden" name="questionnaire_question_id[]" value="'+ item.id +'" />\
                <textarea required name="questionnaire_questions_answers[]" cols="80" placeholder="Digite a resposta aqui" rows="3" id="perguntas"></textarea>');
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: beforeSend: function(){
            $("#col").html('');
        },
 Tinha um "s" a mais em beforeSend

Comment: Erro de digitação. Valeu!

Comment: Pra ficar mais bonitinho, coloca um `$("#col").html('Carregando...');` ou um Spinner Loading no lugar.